# If I kill a looping INSERT query, will it rollback all inserts since the loop started or only the last iteration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, insert, transaction, rollback

Do all inserts or only the current one rollback if the following loop query was killed in the middle of looping?

```
DECLARE @LoopId INT = 1;

WHILE (@LoopId < 100)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table2
    SELECT Field1 
    FROM Table1
    WHERE ForeignKeyField = @LoopId

    SET @LoopId = @LoopId + 1;
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do all inserts or only the current one rollback if the following loop query was killed in the middle of looping?

If the session has started a transaction before the loop, then all statements will be rolled back.  But by default each statement runs in a separate transaction, and only the currently-running INSERT would be rolled back.

Comment: So as long as I don't explicitly start a new transaction outside the loop, then only the currently running INSERT rolls back?

Comment: Yes.  Although if happen to set `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` a transaction will start with the first insert.  But otherwise, yes.

Comment: Great thanks! Also any idea why I saw kind of the opposite behavior when explicitly surrounding the INSERT statement (inside of the loop) with a BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT? I would've thought this would preserve all previous inserts and only rollback the currently active insert on a KILL, but when I stopped it in the middle of running it instantly stopped and then SSMS told me I had uncommitted transactions when I went to close the tab. When I clicked OK to continue closing the tab, it rolled everything back.

Comment: When developing in SSMS it's easy to abort a batch and be left with an open transaction.  Then the next time you run, you're actually using "nested transactions" instead of top-level transactions.